# No overload matches this call in angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular.I was doing a mean project from youtube tutorial then i faced this problem...

[image: This is my code]

[image: This is my code]

[image: Here is my error]

Can you please solve my problem?

[This is my taskservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOvCW.png)

Comment: Which version of rxjs are you using? Try with next/error ```o.subscribe({
   next(x) { 
      // code
   }
});```

Comment: Could you provide your `createTask` method from `taskService`? What is the return data type of that method?

Comment: I have add my taskservice. I am doing a project by watching a youtube tutorial. But his code is running but mine is not running. I have written exact the same code. But my code is not running

Comment: I am using rxjs version (6.6.7)
I am actually new in angular. So if u can describe brifly it will help me a lot.. Thank you

Comment: Please refrain from using screenshots in your questions. Doing so removes the search-ability of the question and users with similar problems will never find this post.  Use the proper markdown tools integrated with the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your createTask method in **taskService** has a return type of Object which is not the type of Task, You need to change it to Task.

Comment: I cant understand. In the tutorial, his code is running , but it doesnt run in my vs code :(

Comment: I think it is because your post and get requests don't have annotation such as .post<Task>(....);

I think you can override it by trying this :.subscribe(newtask as Task) => { ... }

Answer (score 0):

*Remove* frome ngOnInit the type void

```
ngOnInit() { ... }
```

and the type for newTask *to* any

```
.subscribe(newtask: any) => { ... }
```

Comment: But in the tutorial his code is running " (newtask: Task) "

Comment: I don`t see all your code, but there is a common mistake for new people using type in typescript. You can add all code TaskService, Task model, route file ...